# Importing a XML file to MySQL via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a XML file via phpMyAdmin and map each of the child elements to their corresponding fields within a MySQL table. XML sample:

```
<event>
<date>1992</date>
<title>Event Title</title>
<description>Event description goes here.</description>
</event>
```

I have MySQL fields within the table with names identical to the child elements listed above, however, when I import my XML file, I get a message that says "0 queries executed," and of course nothing gets imported.

I tried looking this up via the phpMyAdmin documentation, but I couldn't find anything but a modest description of XML as an import method. How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin doesn't provide a feature to map XML-elements to corresponding table fields. Sorry.

You need to write a program to do this trick. Or enhance phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that seems to be the case. Now the new question is, why is it offered as an import option?

Comment: Probably because other apps may import XML. Moreover XML definitely nicer than CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but, did you try to do a ISO XML? Why dont you try with the head, and all the things that come with the standard XML? If you can't, try CSV. But the way that phpmyadmin parses the files are very specific

Comment: yes, CSV was successful. The XML uploaded error free, but as the other answer states I think I've come to the conclusion that phpMyAdmin doesn't support this kind of upload.